# Is there any option to compile only modified files in Babeljs

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have a PHP project where I am using **babeljs** to convert all my javascript files to **EcmaScript5**. However, the files are so many and every time I edit a piece of code it takes too much time since it compiles whole folder files. 
I tried to search but cannot find a proper solution. 
I would like the **BabelJs** to compile only files which were modified after the last run.

p.s I have two folders for javascript files, `es6` and `js`. A compiled file goes to `js` folder which is visible from the web and `es6` is only for local use.

Here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "webplatform",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Web Platform",
  "scripts": {
    "r8build": "babel htdocs/es6 -d htdocs/js"
  },
  "author": "harry",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-preset-minify": "^0.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

And `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env"],
    ["minify", {
      "builtIns": false
    }]
  ],
  "sourceType": "script"
}
```

Comment: I think this would need to go into the command line arguments. Isn't there also a `--watch` mode?

Comment: @Bergi I have recently started using Node, Babel and trying to figure out how to use it from the command line with `--watch` mode

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#compile-files

Comment: @harshzalavadiya Thank you. Adding file `--watch --copy-files` helped. Full command `babel es6 -d js --watch --copy-files ` first time it compiles all but then it converts only particular file.